# how to update the database with different date in datefield

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I have 3 tables
 1. **event:**`event_id,title,location,latitude,longitude,address,description,email`
 2. **event_time**:`show_id,event_id,start_time,duration,start_date,end_date,date`
 3. **category:**`cat_id,event_id`

I have written this code to update the data,
if i use the update query its not gets edited in the `date` field because date field is not entered by the user,its calculated internally and filled in the field.so its taking same date value to all fields with same event_id.
but i want all other fields same but only date field different,
so i tried to delete the whole event in the database and reinserting the new data.so i have written this,

```
<?php
include_once("webconfig.php");
include_once("webdatabase.php");
$title= isset($_REQUEST['title'])?trim($_REQUEST['title']):"";
$u_id= isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])?trim($_REQUEST['user_id']):"";
$username = isset($_REQUEST['username'])?trim($_REQUEST['username']):"";
$location = isset($_REQUEST['location'])?trim($_REQUEST['location']):"";
$add = isset($_REQUEST['add'])?trim($_REQUEST['add']):"";
$des = isset($_REQUEST['des'])?trim($_REQUEST['des']):"";
$latitude = isset($_REQUEST['latitude'])?trim($_REQUEST['latitude']):"";
$long = isset($_REQUEST['long'])?trim($_REQUEST['long']):"";
$event_id=isset($_REQUEST['event_id'])?trim($_REQUEST['event_id']):"";
$sdate = isset($_REQUEST['sdate'])?trim($_REQUEST['sdate']):"";
$edate=isset($_REQUEST['edate'])?trim($_REQUEST['edate']):"";
$stime = isset($_REQUEST['stime'])?trim($_REQUEST['stime']):"";
$dur = isset($_REQUEST['dur'])?trim($_REQUEST['dur']):"";
//$date=isset($_REQUEST['date'])?trim($_REQUEST['date']):"";

$aryDeparture = explode(":", "$stime"); 
$aryDuration = explode(":", "$dur"); 

$timeDeparture = mktime($aryDeparture[0], $aryDeparture[1]); 

$arrive = date("H:i", strtotime("+" . $aryDuration[0] . " hours +" . $aryDuration[1] . " minutes " , $timeDeparture)); 
$sql ="Delete events,event_time,category from events join event_time join category on(events.event_id=event_time.event_id and event_time.event_id=category.event_id) where event_time. event_id='$event_id'";
mysql_query($sql);

$sql1= "insert into events(event_id,user_id,title,email,location,address,latitude,longitude,description)values('','$u_id','$title','$username','$location','$add','$latitude','$long','$des')";
mysql_query($sql1);
$lastid=mysql_insert_id();
$init_date = strtotime($sdate);
$dst_date = strtotime($edate);
$offset = $dst_date-$init_date;

$dates = floor($offset/60/60/24) + 1;
for ($i = 0; $i< $dates; $i++)
{
$newdate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(12,0,0,date("m", strtotime($sdate)),
(date("d", strtotime($sdate)) + $i), date("Y", strtotime($sdate))));
$sql2="insert into event_time(show_id,event_id,start_date,start_time,end_date,duration,date,end_time) values('','$lastid','$sdate','$stime','$edate','$dur','$newdate','$arrive')";
mysql_query($sql2);
//$sql1="update event_time join events on(events.event_id=event_time.event_id) set events.title='$title',events.location='$location',events.address='$add',events.latitude='$latitude',events.longitude='$long',events.description='$des',event_time.start_time='$stime',event_time.duration='$dur',event_time.start_date='$sdate',event_time.end_date='$edate',event_time.end_time='$arrive',event_time.date='$newdate' where event_time.event_id='$event_id'";
//mysql_query($sql1);
}


//echo $newdate ."<br>";
if(mysql_affected_rows()!=0)
{
$successMsg ="Event Updated Successfully!.";
$xml=
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<root>";
echo "<post>";
echo "<status>True</status>";
echo "<message>$successMsg</message>";
echo "</post>";
echo "</root>";
return $xml;
}
else
{
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<post>';
$xml .= '<status>false</status>';
$xml .= "<message>event not found</message>";
$xml .= '</post>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}
?>
```

now i am able to insert the new data as well as i can get the different data's in date field but i am not getting old event data deleted.please anyone help me.

Comment: please tell the `datatype` of all date fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining the variable `$event_id` before delete.
Your delete query is messy, try to do separated queryes instead and check the errors. 
Dont forget to use backticks around the fields to not get errors related to reserved words.